# How would I download this website so that it works offline?

Tags: download, website

I want to be able to use this tool offline:

http://wigflip.com/ds/

How can I download it so it remains functional?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The web page is not the only part of this application. There is a back-end program creating the images that it generates that is not available to download.

A server program that creates images like this on the back end is ImageMagick.

You would have to have the front page form (which you have via downloading) - a back end form processing program (written in PHP or other server language) that uses ImageMagick to create the image and post it on the web for download.

Answer (score 0):

The submit button makes a request to server which means you should have the serverside code and this is impossible (without hacking). And yes, hacking is bad.

You can press Ctrl+S to save what you see but you can't make it run as it is.

Comment: So how would I go about hacking it?  Just Kidding. Thanks for the info.